# Is sample rate reliable?

Tags: audio, audio-recording, portaudio, audio-device

In audio processing, say the underling library (PortAudio, in my case) gives me a binary, which represents a few seconds of audio captured from a mic, and when it is captured, it used a sample rate of `sr`, and the underling library tells me that this binary consists `nf` number of frames, can I safely assume that the duration of the audio that the binary represents is `nf / sr` seconds?

In another word, if I use a sample rate of `sr`, can I safely assume that I will get `sr` samples per seconds? Will the hardware drop some samples due to some factors (like for limiting power consumption, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that the duration of the audio is `nf / sr` **samples** is correct. Be aware that this assumes the samplerate of your *playback* is also `sr`. This may be not necessarily be the case.

Most audio drivers support a limited set of sampling outputs (44.1 kHZ, 48 kHz, 96kHz, etc). So if say your playback sample rate is `psr` then the actual duration will be `nf / (psr / sr)` seconds.

Note that most audio drivers usually do not drop samples which would result in undesirable audio clicks but, rather simply have higher latency to free up computation for other tasks.

Note that PortAudio isn't meant for playback or recording files as specified in their [FAQ](http://www.portaudio.com/faq.html?search_text=frames).

Comment: Thanks. I don't do playback (except for debugging), so the playback sample rate is not very important here. __PortAudio isn't meant for playback or recording__ I don't see this is mentioned in their FAQ, perhaps you mean playing wave file or write to wave file?

Comment: Yeah, basically no I/O.